# Jquery .load html doesn't initialise bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three pages: `main.html, nav.html, sidebar.html`

I've separated nav and sidebar for my project. In the nav page, I have button for collapsing the sidebar page. I am using bootstrap framework for the theme. But when I separate it, the sidebar doesn't collapse while the button on nav is clicked. Here are the code of main.html

```
<link href="global/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="global/js/main/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#nav" ).load( "inc/nav.html" );
        $( "#sidebar" ).load( "inc/sidebar.html" );
    });
</script>
<div id="nav"></div>
<div class="page-content" style="padding-bottom:70px;">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper bg-white">
        <div class="content">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is nav.html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-indigo navbar-static" style="background:#81018d;">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a href="#" class="d-inline-block">
            <img src="../../assets/images/logo/headerwhite.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-none">
        <button class="navbar-toggler sidebar-mobile-main-toggle legitRipple" type="button">
            <i class="icon-paragraph-justify3"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And sidebar.html

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-dark sidebar-main sidebar-expand-md">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="card card-sidebar-mobile">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar" data-nav-type="accordion">
            <li class="nav-item-header"><div class="text-uppercase font-size-xs line-height-xs">Main</div> <i class="icon-menu" title="Main"></i></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Menu Beranda</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Transaksi</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap only initialises controls when the DOM loads (by default). You need to also do this within the callback of the `load()` methods to instantiate the controls which were dynamically added to the DOM. However, it's worth noting that using AJAX to include content on every page is not a great idea as you're adding extra unnecessary requests to your server. Investigate server side includes instead, assuming your hosting supports them

Comment: In addition to the above, if you load the nav bar / side panel via ajax then you'll get a Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC) where your page will render, your user will start reading then the content will jump about as it loads other parts.  This is not an enjoyable user experience.

Comment: I think I have to seperate it, because I have so many pages. So, if I edit nav.html, the display will also change in every page. Therefore I need to seperate it. Is there any other idea to do such I mean. If we use it in PHP, we only use sintax include("url") to make it work.  But I need it work in html, not in PHP. Please gemme the solution and example...

Comment: Is there anyone can help...